# JavaScript, почему не найдёт функцию array.values()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть простейший код на JS. Запускаю код таким образом: `$ node example.js`

Пример кода:

```
'use strict';
const book = ['sdf', 'asdf', 'sdf'];
const it = book.values();

console.log(it.name());
```

И получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: book.values is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sergey/TestExamplesJavaScript/dist/test.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Данная функция не поддерживается браузерами. - Только `Safari`.

Comment: http://node.green/#ES2015-built-in-extensions-Array-prototype-methods-Array-prototype-values и нодой тоже не поддерживается

Comment: А алтернатива есть ?

Comment: А в какой спецификации у итератора есть метод name?

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать полифилл:

```js
'use strict';
if (!Array.prototype.values) {
  Array.prototype.values = function() {
    return {
      [Symbol.iterator]: () => {
        let i = 0;
        return {
          next: () => (i < this.length) ? 
                 {done: false, value: this[i++]} :
                 {done: true}}}}}}

const a = [2, 3, 5, 8];
const it = a.values();

for (let v of it) {
  console.log(v);
}
```

А можно итерировать массив:

```js
const a = [3, 5, 8, 13];

for (let v of a) {
  console.log(v);
}
```

Разница только в том, что итератор только для чтения.